# Convert FormFile to Java.io.File

Tags: java, forms, file, struts

I have an object `FormFile` recovered through a Struts Form .
I have to convert `Java` side in the `java.io.File`
How can I do? The casting in this way by exception:

```
File myFile = (File) fileFormFile
```

Comment: You're probably not the first one who's looking for that job. Have you search online before asking?

Comment: A `java.IO.File` is little more than the path to a file and some utility methods. If you want to save an object to disk, you will need `FileOutputStream` and similar classes.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I found something you might use:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/54902/Struts/Struts-FormFile-java-io-File

Answer (score 0):

Read the API document of [FromFile](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/api/org/apache/struts/upload/FormFile.html) class what methods it all provides. Use [getInputStream()](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/api/org/apache/struts/upload/FormFile.html#getInputStream%28%29) method.